# regex doesn't find last word in my string

Tags: java, string

I have a regular expression [a-z]\d to unpack the text witch is compressed by simple rule
hellowoooorld  -> hel2owo4rld
So now i have to unpack my text and it doesn't work correctly. It can't find last word in my String
it always like skip gu4ys

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("Hel2o peo7ple it is ou6r wo3rld gu4ys");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]\\d");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            int startWord = matcher.start();
            int numLetters = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(startWord + 1, startWord + 2));
            text.deleteCharAt(startWord + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < numLetters - 1; ++i) {
                text.insert(startWord + 1, text.charAt(startWord));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(text);
```

Result is : Hello peooooooople it is ouuuuuur wooorld gu4ys
I expect this : Hello peooooooople it is ouuuuuur wooorld guuuuys
I can't understand why it doesn't work all is simple

Comment: What about https://ideone.com/P1m10a? What is your targeted Java version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like Java's Matcher checks your string size when it initializes, and doesn't go past that. You are inserting to the string, which makes it longer. The matcher doesn't check that far.

A quick, though slow, fix is to re-initialize the matcher every time.

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("Hel2o peo7ple it is ou6r wo3rld gu4ys");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]\\d");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        
while (matcher.find()) {
    int startWord = matcher.start();
    int numLetters = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(startWord + 1, startWord + 2));
    text.deleteCharAt(startWord + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < numLetters - 1; ++i) {
        text.insert(startWord + 1, text.charAt(startWord));
    }
            
    matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
}
System.out.println(text);
```

A faster approach would find the numbers, calculate the string length and then manually construct the string using the found numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that the matcher is only finding the pattern [a-z]\d, which matches a single letter followed by a digit, but it is not finding the last word "gu4ys" because it doesn't match that pattern.

To fix this, you can modify the regular expression to include an optional group that matches any remaining letters at the end of the text.

Try this regex and please let me know if it worked :)
"[a-z]\d|[a-z]+"

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it cand find string that i need

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).